# Catch errors in async functions and test them via jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, jestjs

I'm trying to catch errors in my async functions and test those functions using jest.

```
import Db from './lib/db'
const db = new Db()

export async function example (id) {
  await db.connect().catch(err => console.error(err))
  const Data = db.connection.collection('data')

  return Data.updateOne(
    { id },
    { $set: { anything: 'else' } }
  ).catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

But the test returns me the error:

> TypeError: db.connect(...).catch is not a function

So what am I doing wrong? The testing or the catching?

```
test('should call mongoDB updateOne() method', async () => {
  // SETUP
  let Data = db.connection.collection('data')
  Data.updateOne = jest.fn()
  // EXECUTE
  expect.assertions(1)
  await example({
    id: 'id'
  }).then((res) => {
    // VERIFY
    expect(Data.updateOne).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: What is `./lib/db`, does it work outside of the test? Are you mocking the `db` somehow?

Comment: I don't think you should try to access `db.connection` after `db.connect()` has failed. Just don't handle the rejection there, let it propagate up. Same thing for effectively ignoring errors on `updateOne()`, the caller of your function has no way to know whether the update actually worked or not.

Comment: @Bergi You are right, but I don't see where to put the catch if connection to db is failing or any mongodb method is failing after user is calling the function.

Comment: You should put the error handling on the `example` call, like `example().then(onSuccess, onError)` or `try { await example() } catch(e) { … }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`Db.ts`:

```js
import console = require('console');

export class Db {
  public connection = {
    collection(model: string) {
      return {
        async updateOne(...args) {
          console.log('update one');
        }
      };
    }
  };
  public async connect() {
    console.log('connect db');
  }
}
```

`example.ts`:

```js
import { Db } from './Db';

const db = new Db();

export async function example(id) {
  await db.connect().catch(err => console.error(err));
  const Data = db.connection.collection('data');

  return Data.updateOne({ id }, { $set: { anything: 'else' } }).catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

`example.spec.ts`:

```js
import { example } from './example';
import { Db } from './Db';

jest.mock('./Db.ts', () => {
  const collectionMocked = {
    updateOne: jest.fn()
  };
  const connectionMocked = {
    collection: jest.fn(() => collectionMocked)
  };

  const DbMocked = {
    connect: jest.fn(),
    connection: connectionMocked
  };
  return {
    Db: jest.fn(() => DbMocked)
  };
});

const db = new Db();

describe('example', () => {
  test('should call mongoDB updateOne() method', async () => {
    const Data = db.connection.collection('data');
    (db.connect as jest.MockedFunction<any>).mockResolvedValueOnce({});
    (Data.updateOne as jest.MockedFunction<any>).mockResolvedValueOnce('mocked value');
    const actualValue = await example('1');
    expect(actualValue).toBe('mocked value');
    expect(Data.updateOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ id: '1' }, { $set: { anything: 'else' } });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/57515192/example.spec.ts
  example
    ✓ should call mongoDB updateOne() method (6ms)

------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files   |       75 |      100 |    33.33 |      100 |                   |
 example.ts |       75 |      100 |    33.33 |      100 |                   |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.336s, estimated 6s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57515192